# python pytesseract.image_to_string unable to read clear text in image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

I am using python3.6 and Tesseract-OCR on my mac. I have pictures containing the text which is clearly readable. However, despite that it is super clear to the human eyes, the Tesseract can't extract them correctly. The attached one is the extreme case that nothing is returned

[image]

Below is the snapshot of the code I am using

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('frame40.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, (600, 450))
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: you can try [Easy-OCR](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR). It might work well in your case.

Comment: If you know that the text is white, you may convert to grayscale and apply threshed: `text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 230 , 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1])`. I don't want to post this as an answer, because I guess this is not what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

can you using image high resolution and size and using threshold image values to get better result

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).